# Storing The Output of a Permutation as a List of Lists

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, permutation

When I run the following code I get rows of tuples:

```
  {perm = itertools.permutations(['A','B','C','D','E','F'],4)

   for val in perm:
        print(val)}.
```

How do I make the code give me the output as a single list of lists instead of rows of tuples?

When I run the code I get something like this
('F', 'E', 'B', 'C')
('F', 'E', 'B', 'D')
('F', 'E', 'C', 'A')
('F', 'E', 'C', 'B')

```
type here
```

etc.

What I want is something like this

```
      [['F', 'E', 'B', 'C'],
       ['F', 'E', 'B', 'D'],
       ['F', 'E', 'C', 'A'],...,]
```

Comment: cast val into a list and append it to another list

Comment: `pprint.pprint(list(map(list, itertools.permutations('ABCDEF',4))))` gives exactly the output you specified.

Answer (score 0):

cast `val` into a list and append it to another list.

```
import itertools
perm = itertools.permutations(['A','B','C','D','E','F'],4)

result = []
for val in perm:
    result.append(list(val))

print(result)
```

The question is, do you want to generate all permutations and store them?

As you have it now, the generator will give you one permutation each time, which is memory efficient.

You can generate all of them into a list of lists, but just think if you really want that, since the number of permutations could be very large.

Comment: Thanks but when I try that it doesn't give me a single list of lists, it gives me various list of lists e.g   [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
                   [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E']]
                   [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'F']]

Comment: How do I store it as a single list of lists?

Comment: @Thando I cannot reproduce what you are saying. In my computer it gives a single list of lists: A list  containing 360 lists of 4 elements. Are you running exactly the my code as is?

Comment: Yes sir, I only add print(result) below the last line of your code

Comment: Are you sure you are running exactly my code? could you take a screenshot, upload it to pastebin and post the link in a comment?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've noticed that when I put print(result) directly in line with the previous line of the code I get various list of lists. However when I backspace print(result) like you've done I get a single list of lists. My question is, why is that the case?

Comment: Because indentation is paramount in python. It's the way of determining if your print is inside the loop or outside (Python doesn't use braces like other languages, but relies on indentation). I would recommend looking at a python tutorial, since this is a very important thing, that will make your programs do very different things depending on how your lines are indented

Comment: Okay thanks, what happens if I don't indent the line:    result.append(list(val))

Comment: Try it and you will see. I recommend that you read a python tutorial, so you understand what indentation does. Then feel free to try things, see what happens and understand why they happen. If you take the line out of the loop several things will happen: 1) your loop will become empty, requiring a `pass` instruction. 2) you will only append the last permutation to result, which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: I want to use the single list of lists elsewhere in my code but how am I sure that I'm getting the single list of lists and not the various lists of lists?

Comment: I asked you a screenshot of the code you are running, since the code I posted produces exactly one list of lists as you want. Please share a screenshot showing the code you are running and the result you are getting.

Comment: Okay, how do I upload to paste bin?

Comment: Can I just email it to you?

Comment: sorry, for images you can use imgur. pastebin is only for text

Comment: I've never used that before. Where do I go in order to upload on imgur. pastebin?